# How to resolve this ORA-01722: invalid number error in SQL *Loader based concurrent program?

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader, oracle-apps

I am using a sql * loader based concurrent program to upload .csv to Oracle database table.

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Production_Plan
(
  PROCESS     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  SKU         VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  MACHINE     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  PRODUCTION  NUMBER
)
```

And a sample row from .csv table is:
[image]

After the concurrent program run, it gives warning and log file shows:

> ```
> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table Production_Plan, column PRODUCTION. ORA-01722: invalid number
> ```

But, if I import the same data as an excel file by TOAD it doesn't raise any error

Answer (score 1):

Control file; for simplicity, I put sample data in there. Note `to_number` function applied to the `production` column.

```
load data
infile *
replace
into table production_plan
fields terminated by ';'
(process,
 sku,
 machine,
 production "to_number(:production, '999.99')"
)

begindata
sample process;0.12 x 770;sample machine;11.3
```

Loading session and the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test3.ctl log=test3.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sub Svi 1 13:25:57 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1

SQL> select * From production_plan;

PROCESS              SKU                  MACHINE              PRODUCTION
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
sample process       0.12 x 770           sample machine             11,3

SQL>
```

Comment: I have modified my .ctl file as-> Options (skip=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'INFILE PATH'
APPEND
INTO TABLE Production_Plan
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS          
(
PROCESS,
SKU,
MACHINE,
PRODUCTION "to_number(:PRODUCTION, '999.99')"
) But it gave same error again